# Controller is undefined in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

**karma.config.js:**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'node_modules/angular-translate/dist/angular-translate.min.js',
      'browser/javascripts/*.js',
      'browser/tests/*.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

**home.spec.js:**

```
describe('Home Controller', function() {
  beforeEach(
    module('pascalprecht.translate'),
    module('tradeshiftApp')
  );
  var $controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  it('should exist', function(){
    controller = $controller('HomeController', {
      $scope: {}
    });
    expect(controller).not.toBe(undefined);
  })
});
```

I am using `karma-jasmine` and the problem is following: my `app.js` file has this module and it's loading correctly:

```
var app = angular.module('tradeshiftApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);
```

But when I try to mock my controller, which is

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $req, $window, $translate, $q) { 
  // some code 
});
```

I get an error, which says that `HomeController` is not a function. As you can see, dependencies are wired up and everything **should** be fine, I guess. Any tips?

**Note:** I've tried to inject `$rootScope` and get `$rootScope.$new()` and it's successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in `'pascalprecht.translate'` module. In my code I have a small dependency wired to the foregoing module, which was included in my HTML file, but not in my Karma config file. Guys, be careful and vigilant about your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('pascalprecht.translate', [])
      angular.mock.module('tradeshiftApp')
   }
);
```

Comment: it throws an error `TypeError: queueableFn.fn.call is not a function`